# Find a Hermitian Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We are given two column matrices A and B. Can we find a Hermitian matrix $H$ such that
$ A_{4 \times 1} = H_{4 \times 4} B_{4\times 1} $ ?

We tried to solve it by multiplying a $1\times4$ row matrix to the above equation,
$ A_{4\times 1} C_{1\times 4} = H_{4\times 4} B_{4\times 1} C_{1\times 4}$ and then taking the inverse of the new $4\times4$ matrix formed but it doesn't ensure hermiticity of H.

Comment: notice that $B^*A=B^*HB$ must be a real number ($B^*$ is $B$ transposed and complex conjugated). If this is satisfied and $B\neq0$ then $H$ exists, you can reduce it to a 2x2 matrix problem

Answer (score 0):

Given two vectors $x\ne0$ and $y$, can we find a Hermitian matrix $H$ such that $y=Hx$?

We may assume that $x$ is a unit vector. Then $y=Hx$ if and only if $U^\ast y=(U^\ast HU)U^\ast x$ for any unitary matrix $U$. Let $U$ be a unitary matrix such that its first column is $x$, so that $U^\ast x=(1,0,\ldots,0)^T$. Now the rest is trivial.

Comment: The above deals with a particular case when we have x as a unit vector. What if x is not a unit vector?

Comment: @SohanSarangi $Hx=(\|x\|H)\frac{x}{\|x\|}$.